# Access violation at address 09A878EE in module

Tags: delphi, access-violation

I have this problem that I could solve this by throwing me this error, brother I press a button that invokes a form Cencillo doing a search. The error is as follows.

[image]

**Message : Access violation at address 09A878EE in module 'Almacen.pgi'. Read of address 00000000.**

And the code of the button which gives me this error is as follows:

```
procedure TfListaEntregaBodegas.SBBuscarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  FBuscarRequisicionBodega := TFBuscarRequisicionBodega.Create(Application);
  FBuscarRequisicionBodega.dsRequisicionBodega.DataSet:=qListaRequisiciones;
  FBuscarRequisicion.ShowModal;
  FBuscarRequisicion.Free;
  dbgListaRequisiciones.Setfocus;
end;
```

Comment: What language is this?  I'm assuming Delphi from your question history.

Comment: One of the objects is `nil`. Use the debugger to find out which one it is.

Comment: At least `FBuscarRequisicion` will become a dangling pointer after the first call of this event method (after the first click on the button).

Comment: Am I the only one wondering what a `.pgi` is?

Comment: You asked the question but have gone silent. Do you still want help?

Comment: there are occasions that are not fully understood as the thing work, but the only thing I did was swap two lines of code. 7 and 8

Comment: @JeissonNiño: Have you ever spend a second thinking about clicking on the "contents" label or looking at which line you are in your code when the exception is raised? For the NIL pointer, we have at least three candidates. And a (potential) memory leak with `FBuscarRequisicionBodega` when the routine is called twice and the instance has not been freed in the meantime (which we don't see), plus the already mentioned dangling pointer.

Comment: You're also giving the ownership of `FBuscarRequisicion` to the `Application`, which means the app its self will free it when it's terminated - but then you free it anyway. I assume you want to pass `nil` instead of `Application`.

Comment: @J...: I don't know what a `.pgi` is either, but just in case you don't know, Windows will execute a file with a non-executable extension; I use that trick occasionally to debug those obscure bugs that can't be replicated on dev/test. Set the output path to the production system, change the application extension to something like `.exd` or `.xyz`, do a build (which puts `Project.exd` on the production system alongside the real one), set a breakpoint, and **carefully** debug. Spot the problem, reverse the above (clear the extension and output path), and fix it. Delete the `.exd` afterward.

Comment: @KenWhite Fancy and brilliant.  I like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apparent problem is on the commented lines below, where you create something called `TFBuscarRequisicionBodega` and assign it to a variable named `FBuscarRequisicionBodega` and set a few properties of `FBuscarRequisicionBodega`. You then call `ShowModal` on an *entirely different variable* named `FBuscarRequisicion` and free it afterward. You've now orphaned `FBuscarRequisicionBodega` (nothing ever frees it), and at the same time called `ShowModal` on something you haven't provided code for (`FBuscarRequisicion`), and freed it afterward. Clicking the button a second time will then call `ShowModal` on something you've freed the last time through.

This problem seems pretty clear to spot, without even reading the variable names - just examine these two lines of code:

```
  FBuscarRequisicionBodega.dsRequisicionBodega.DataSet:=qListaRequisiciones;
  FBuscarRequisicion.ShowModal;
```

See how the variable name lengths don't match? (The `.` doesn't line up, because the first one has six more letters than the second one.)

Read the variable names very carefully in the code you've posted, and the problem seems very clear. (Two seconds with the debugger will tell you for sure; you really should learn to use it).

```
procedure TfListaEntregaBodegas.SBBuscarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;

  // You create something and assign it to one variable here.
  // Set debugger breakpoint on next line (F5, click the grey 
  // gutter to the left of the editor line numbers, or right-click
  // the line and choose Debug->Toggle Breakpoint, run your app (F9),
  // and step through the code with F8.
  FBuscarRequisicionBodega := TFBuscarRequisicionBodega.Create(Application);
  FBuscarRequisicionBodega.dsRequisicionBodega.DataSet:=qListaRequisiciones;

  // You then call ShowModal on a totally different variable here, then
  // free it after ShowModal returns.
  FBuscarRequisicion.ShowModal;
  FBuscarRequisicion.Free;
  dbgListaRequisiciones.Setfocus;
end;
```